Empty Results Field after Implementing Filter Search
I've created a cardsByLanguage promise in my api file for my projected, inserted a navbar item for for a filtered results search, and created a click event listener for this navbar item, but no cards display. In my promise, I first filtered for language and then by uid, so both options should be filtered.
I put the following function for my api js file:
const cardsByLanguage = (language, uid) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fetch(`${endpoint}/vocab.json?orderBy="language"&equalTo="${language}"`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      const filteredData = Object.values(data).filter((card) => card.uid === uid);
      resolve(filteredData);
    })
    .catch(reject);
});

And I've put the following for a navbar click event listener:
 document.querySelector('#allLanguages').addEventListener('click', () => {
    cardsByLanguage(`${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}`).then(showCards);
  });


Avoid the Promise constructor antipattern!

" but no cards display": there is nothing in the code you have shared that actually displays. What have you debugged? The cardsByLanguage expects two arguments, of which the second is the uid, but you call it with just one argument, which is the uid. So this is bound to go wrong. But even after you correct that, there is no way we can tell if this would work as we don't know the values of the variables involved.
